# Can't clone GitHub repo in Remix

Tags: remix, ide, repositories

I am getting the following error when trying to clone a GitHub repo from `Remix`:

```
An error occurred: Please check that you have the correct URL for the repo. If the repo is private, you need to add your github credentials (with the valid token permissions) in Settings plugin
```

My repo is private and I was able to clone it yesterday. I have checked and my credentials are also the right ones.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It was a computer issue, unrelated to Ethereum.

Comment: Ok, should I do anything to close the question?

Comment: I already closed it. For more general questions about development you could use stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this ever happens to you and you were able to clone the repo before, the solution is to simply restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few possible issues that could be causing this error. Here are a few things you could try:

Make sure that you have the correct URL for your repository. The URL should be in the format https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git.

1. Check that you have the correct permissions to access the repository. If you are a collaborator on the repository, you should have access, but if you are trying to access a repository that you do not have explicit permissions for, you will need to request access or use a different repository.
2. Make sure that you are using a personal access token (PAT) with the correct permissions. The PAT should have the repo scope to allow read access to private repositories.
3. If you have recently changed the visibility of the repository (e.g. from public to private), there may be a delay before the changes take effect. In this case, waiting a few minutes and trying again may resolve the issue.
4. If none of these suggestions help, you may want to try deleting and re-adding your GitHub credentials in the Remix Settings plugin to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

set the email in github plugin, then it work!